# Is it okay to async modernizr?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, modernizr

Google PageSpeed test is telling me to use `async`

E.g. change

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>`

To

`<script async src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>`

Will modernizer still work just fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modernizr needs to be placed in the `<head>` for two reasons:

1. html5shiv needs to be there for oldIE.
2. avoiding the FOUC when using modernizr-placed classes for
   feature-conditional styling

You can use an async attribute and/or place it at the bottom if neither of these matter to you.

Look at this issue posted in [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/878)

Comment: `Modernizr needs to be placed in the for two reasons` - In the what? head section?

Comment: Formatting issue :) Updated the answer now.

Comment: Hmm, well I only need html5shiv and I don't really use conditions so I guess no `async` for me

Answer (score 3):

Modernizr **does not** need to be placeed in `<head>`.

Modernizr will work ultimately fine whenever you include it.

If you make modernizr script **async**, or include it after some of significant page loading events (`DOMContentLoaded`, `window.onload`...)

- application of specific css rules (`feature`, `no-feature` classes in document's `head`) **will be delayed**.
- availibility of `window.Modernizr` will also be delayed, together with it's object properties (i.e. `Modernizr.propery`)

In short,

- bad thing that may happen to your `CSS` if you use `async` loading of Modernizr is improper styles (the ones that depends on `<html>` classes) applied for some time
- bad thing that may happen to your `JS` code is, if you use `Modernizr` global object, you may not use it directly as it may and may not be loaded - you will have to *wait for it* by some manner. So, no more:

```
if(Modernizr.cssanimations){
    // your feature-dependant code
}
```

but instead:

```
if(typeof Modernizr !== "undefined"){
//uitilize Modernizr global object here
} else {
// implement waiting for this object, let's say write short onModernizrLoad() function...
}
```